# Trying to POST txt files using web api, getting 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: javascript, c#, post, asp.net-web-api

Im new to `c#` and currently trying to `POST` several `txt` files to the server using web API, cannot get this to work. Following [this](https://cmatskas.com/upload-files-to-the-server-using-javascript-and-mvc-webapi/) article, I'm `append`ing the files to `formData` and posting it using the following code:

```
public uploadMethod(formDataWithFiles) {
    return this.$http.post("/actionApi/Utils/UploadFile", formDataWithFiles).then((res) => {
        return res;
    }).catch((err) => {
        return err;
    });
}
```

This is the backend code that supposed to receive the files and parse them:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, "The request doesn't contain valid content!");
    }

    try
    {
        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
        {
            var dataStream = await file.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            // use the data stream to persist the data to the server (file system etc)

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent("Successful upload", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(@"text/html");
            return response;
        }
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,"problem.");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e.Message);
    }
}
```

The exception I get:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Request body:

```
General:

    Request URL: http://localhost:48738/actionApi/Utils/UploadFile
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request Headers:
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer _en....
Origin: http://localhost:48738
Referer: http://localhost:48738/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 

(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36

Request Patload:
------WebKitFormBoundaryYAuasRL66eAdhUtd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="34.txt"; filename="34.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundaryYAuasRL66eAdhUtd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="35.txt"; filename="35.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include a minimal example of the request body (press F12 in your browser, go to the network tab, make the request and it should appear in the list). No doubt you're falling foul of your `Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()` requirement.

Comment: @john Please see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your response, the http header `Content-Type` is  incorrect, which should instead be 
`Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

This might be caused by your Javascript code, so please use the code below as an example of how file-uploading ajax is triggered for angularJS

```js
var filedata = $("#fileupload").prop("files")[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", filedata);
var uploadUrl = "/actionApi/Utils/UploadFile";
uploadMethod(uploadUrl, formData);

function uploadMethod(uploadUrl, form_data) {
  $http
    .post(uploadUrl, form_data, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: { "Content-Type": undefined }
    })
    .success(function() {})
    .error(function() {});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just changed the content type to what you suggested `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` but still the same reply from server `415 (Unsupported Media Type)`

Comment: which HTTP library did you use at javascript? jQuery , axios or others?

Comment: I'm using `angularjs`

Comment: That did the trick! thanks! Could you explain `transformRequest: angular.identity,` ?

Comment: transformRequest function by default will process any data we passed(here is form_data) by serializing it and to avoid this, we set  identity function to keep the format of form_data unchanged. because we do expect it to be "multipart/form-data"  which in turn "Content-Type": undefined  will do it us.